# What is the meaning of "four‑o" here?

Tags: meaning

This is a piece of text from a novel, what is the meaning of "four-o" here?

> And I stand here before you and tell you I'm perfectly sane. I do have one slightly crooked wheel upstairs, but everything else is ticking along just **four‑o,** thank you very much.

Comment: Which novel? (there are many)

Comment: In context, it apparently means "working properly". But I've never heard the expression. Maybe it's specific to this novel, or maybe it's specific to some profession or sub-culture that I'm not familiar with. I've been speaking English for 60+ years so if it was a common English idiom I think I'd have at least heard of it.

Comment: Perhaps a reference to "4.0 average grade" in the us educational system (meaning "as good a possible) Knowing the source would help.

Comment: Try 'oh' instead of 'o'. Urban Dictionary: _Four-Oh: Derived from the word "chill", as 40 degrees Fahrenheit is a pretty cool temperature; Four-Oh can replace the word "chill" or "cool" in any situation._

Comment: Also in Urban Dictionary is [Four-O](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Four-O) meaning 'great' in most of the contexts given.

Comment: Well I found the book,  Rage, by Stephen King.  Hard to find because it has been withdrawn from print by the Author.  There is a line a couple of paragraphs earlier about "a drunk driver dong one-ten", That would fit with the "crooked wheel" metaphor. so it could be that, or the GPA thing, or the "forty-fahrenheit=cool".  The meaning in context is clear enough, even if this particular piece of slang is no longer in circulation.

Comment: @JamesK - of course, for me, forty degrees of temperature puts me in mind of a certain August I spent in Barcelona

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: @JamesK Surely "a drunk driver dong one-ten" is a reference to their speed 110MPH.

Comment: @peter, yes. It's possible that the idea here is that "although I have a crooked wheel, the rest of my brain is doing an efficient and safe 40mph".  Someone can put up a wiki answer if nobody can get any better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a common idiom in modern English.

The context makes the meaning completely clear. It means "fine", "okay", "no problems".  Most native speakers would skip over this without worrying about it.

The context is that this is a psychotic killer's first-person narrative. And they have been discussing how most people have a dark side that they don't think about. In the previous discussion he talks about a drunk driver going "one-ten", that is evidently "110 mph".  Perhaps this character tends to talk about car speeds like that.  If so, it does match the metaphor of the "crooked wheel upstairs". That is "my brain (=upstairs) is like a car that has one crooked wheel, but the rest of the car is travelling at a safe and efficient speed of 40 (four-o) mph".

Alternatively, Urbandictionary (a sometimes unreliable source) says that "four-o" is slang for "Forty Fahrenheit" and means "cool".  Ie my brain is fine and everything is cool.

Or, as the character is a student, it might be a reference to 4.0 average grade (a perfect grade in the US system) "My brain is running perfectly, and getting perfect marks."

There may be other interpretations. But the choice of interpretation doesn't matter. The meaning is completely clear.